# Replace a character from all columns in Hive tables

Tags: hive

I need to perform regex replace function on all columns in my Hive table.
Is there a way to perform the operation on all columns without calling out each column individually?

Comment: you can write a shell script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp_replace. Below is the syntax for Hive REGEXP_REPLACE Function.
`regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    val col : DataFrame = hiveContext.sql("show columns in dbname.table_name")
    val arry  = col.collectAsList().toArray

    def regexpReplace(x: AnyRef): String =
    return "select regexp_replace(" + x + ",[^0-9a-zA-Z]," + "' ')  from dbname.tbl_name"

  for(  col <- arry)
    {
      val res = regexpReplace(col.toString.substring(1,x.toString.length-1))
      sqlContext.sql(res)
    }
```